# How do I run doctests with Twisted Trial?

Tags: python, twisted

I have Python code in `addition.py` which defines doctests like so:

```
def increment(n):
    """
    >>> increment(1)
    2
    """
    return n + 1
```

I am already using Twisted Trial to run other tests. My directory structure looks like this:

```
setup.py
src
└── mathematics
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── addition.py
    └── test_addition.py
```

That is, `addition.py` defines an `addition` module in the `mathematics` package. How do I get Trial to load and run the doctests found there?

Comment: What file is your `increment()` function in?

Comment: Good point. I have edited to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

When loading test modules (those which are named with a `test` prefix), Trial looks for a `__doctests__` global. The value is a list of packages to search for doctests.

To run doctests for the above code, add this to `test_addition.py`:

```
__doctests__ = ['mathematics.addition']
```